# Plot json data on D3.js in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, d3.js

I have following data

```
export const graphData = [
  {
    part_number: "N3241Z",
    serial_number: "40615705",
    date: "2022-12-16T00:00:00",
    part_desc: "PANEL ASSY, MODE CONTROL",
    action: "installed",
    description: "",
    service_bulletin: "SB-787-22-0002-03--.pdf",
  },
  {
    part_number: "N3241AZ",
    serial_number: "40615705",
    date: "2022-12-16T00:00:00",
    part_desc: "PANEL ASSY, MODE CONTROL",
    action: "installed",
    description: "",
    service_bulletin: "SB-787-22-0002-03--.pdf",
  },
  {
    part_number: "N3241AZ",
    serial_number: "40615705",
    date: "2022-12-16T00:00:00",
    part_desc: "PANEL ASSY, MODE CONTROL",
    action: "removed",
    description: "",
    service_bulletin: "SB-787-22-0002-03--.pdf",
  },
  {
    part_number: "N3241AZ",
    serial_number: "40615705",
    date: "2022-12-16T00:00:00",
    part_desc: "PANEL ASSY, MODE CONTROL",
    action: "wo_created",
    description: "",
    service_bulletin: "SB-787-22-0002-03--.pdf",
  },
  {
    part_number: "N3241ZX",
    serial_number: "40615705",
    date: "2022-12-16T00:00:00",
    part_desc: "PANEL ASSY, MODE CONTROL",
    action: "installed",
    description: "",
    service_bulletin: "SB-787-22-0002-03--.pdf",
  },
  {
    part_number: "N3241TZ",
    serial_number: "40615705",
    date: "2022-12-16T00:00:00",
    part_desc: "PANEL ASSY, MODE CONTROL",
    action: "wo_created",
    description: "",
    service_bulletin: "SB-787-22-0002-03--.pdf",
  },
  {
    part_number: "N3241TZCD",
    serial_number: "40615705",
    date: "2022-12-16T00:00:00",
    part_desc: "PANEL ASSY, MODE CONTROL",
    action: "wo_created",
    description: "",
    service_bulletin: "SB-787-22-0002-03--.pdf",
  },
];
```

I want this data to be plotted in d3.js where on y-axis there is date, and on x axis there are part_numbers and actions should be on zIndex, there can be multiple actions wrt part_number and date i.e there can be multiple objects with same part_number and date but different action
Below is the UI I wanted to achieve am newbie to d3.js, please help

[This is the UI i want to achive](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lnluW.png)

```
import {
  useEffect,
  useState,
  useRef,
  useCallback,
  useLayoutEffect,
} from 'react';
import { Flex } from '@core-ui/components';
// eslint-disable-next-line import/no-extraneous-dependencies
import * as d3 from 'd3';
import { ASSET_ACTIONS } from '../../util/types';

interface GanttChartProps {
  readonly uniqueAssets: any[];
  readonly filteredTableData: any[];
  readonly filteredData: any[];
  readonly themeVariant: string;
  readonly selectedElements: number[];
}

const getCodeChipColor = (code: string) => {
  switch (code) {
    case ASSET_ACTIONS.INSTALL:
      return '#DB9C09';
    case ASSET_ACTIONS.FAULTCODE:
      return '#CC4948';
    case ASSET_ACTIONS.REMOVED:
      return '#4BABBF';
    case ASSET_ACTIONS.WO_CREATED:
      return '#4CAF80';
    default:
      return null;
  }
};

export const GanttChart: React.FC<GanttChartProps> = ({
  uniqueAssets,
  filteredTableData,
  filteredData,
  themeVariant,
  selectedElements,
}) => {
  const svgRef = useRef<any>(null);
  const visibleAssets = selectedElements.map(
    (index: number) => uniqueAssets[index],
  );
  const uniqueDates = filteredTableData.map(d => d.date);
  useLayoutEffect(() => {
    console.log(selectedElements);

    const margin = { top: 20, right: 20, bottom: 30, left: 100 };
    const width = 1000 - margin.left - margin.right;
    const height = 900 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

    const svg = d3
      .select(svgRef.current)
      .attr('width', width + margin.left + margin.right)
      .attr('height', height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
      .append('g')
      .attr('transform', `translate(${margin.left},${margin.top})`);

    const x: any = d3.scaleBand().range([0, width]).padding(0.1);

    const y: any = d3.scaleBand().range([0, height]).padding(0.1);

    const xAxis = d3.axisTop(x).tickSize(0);

    const yAxis = d3.axisLeft(y).tickSize(0);

    // Update scales and axes with new data
    x.domain(visibleAssets);
    y.domain(uniqueDates);

    svg.append('g').call(xAxis).selectAll('.tick text');
    svg.append('g').call(yAxis);

    const bars = svg.selectAll('.bar').data(filteredData, d => d.part_number);

    // Remove old bars
    bars.exit().remove();

    // Update existing bars
    bars
      .attr('x', d => x(d.part_number))
      .attr('y', d => y(d.date))
      .attr('width', x.bandwidth())
      .style('fill', d => getCodeChipColor(d.action));

    // Append new bars
    bars
      .enter()
      .append('rect')
      .attr('class', 'bar')
      .attr('x', d => x(d.part_number))
      .attr('y', d => y(d.date))
      .attr('width', x.bandwidth())
      .attr('height', 20) // You can adjust the height of the bars as needed
      .style('fill', d => getCodeChipColor(d.action));
  }, [filteredData, selectedElements, filteredTableData]);

  return (
    <Flex
      shrink
      align="center"
      justify="center"
      css={{ flexDirection: 'column', width: '100%' }}>
      <svg ref={svgRef} />
    </Flex>
  );
};
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: @CodeThing I have tried this but unable to achive the  zIndex part
https://codesandbox.io/s/mystifying-forest-v0kjwi?file=/src/Graph.js:0-2098

Comment: The image you link is an example of a [Gantt chart](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gantt_chart) and there is a [tag with over 800 questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/gantt-chart) dedicated to the topic. Here's [my favorite answer on the topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74554883#74554883).

Comment: @MarkMcClure is not gantt chart, it is some what tabular structure, can someone help with this

Comment: Yes, you've got a table with time on one axis and categories on the other, which is exactly what a Gantt chart is. It's very difficult to helps someone without knowing what kind of code they've tried.

Comment: @MarkMcClure I have added the code snippet for things I tried, things have started to fall in place, but currently, I am facing the issue in which old svg elements are not getting removed when the state is updated in dependency array